# During the Passion - What laws might Jesus and his disciples been accused of breaking?

Tags: contradiction, gospels, sabbath, passion-narrative, passover

<sup>**Related to:**
[Luke 22 : What was Jesus' Basis to Order His Disciples to Violate the Passover Sabbath?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/27264/luke-22-what-was-jesus-basis-to-order-his-disciples-to-violate-the-passover-s)</sup>

---

## 1. Question -

During the Passion Narrative<sup>1</sup> - ***What laws might Jesus and his disciples been accused of breaking*** - according to Scripture and Jewish authorities - at that time.

<sup>1. **The Passion Narrative in the Four Gospels** : Matthew 26-28; Mark 14:16; Luke 22-24; John 13:21;</sup>

---

## 2. Scope :

This should not include Jewish law from later Amoraim portions of the Mishnah (Tannaim is okay), not from the Talmud, and not from later Passover Halakhic requirements after the Temple Period, (like the four cups of wine, etc).

Comment: According to who?

Comment: I don't know why your questions are getting downvoted. I find them to be intelligent. +1. Sorry I don't have an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "traditionalists." Traditional what? Why are you writing for anybody but yourself? Write for yourself :-)

Comment: When I say, "write for yourself," I don't mean to ignore the standards or reader and to write your own opinions. That's unprofessional and wrong. It's right to honor what's expected and it's amateur not to show your sources and how you have derived what you've derived. But writing can be difficult, so when it's not appreciated, even when it's good, it can help to find a reason for writing that doesn't involve other people -especially virtual people. You do it 'right' but you do it for yourself (or God or whatever), and then the research becomes about learning. You leave your ego at the door.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<sup>Setting this as a community wiki - for collaboration</sup>

Organization: **1.)** Actions Taken that May "Appear" to be Violations; **2.)** Bases for the Commands;

---

## 1. Actions Taken that May "Appear" to be Violations :

> **NASB, Luke 22:15** - And He said to them, “I have earnestly desired to eat this Passover with you before I suffer; 16 for I say to you, I shall never again eat it until it is fulfilled in the kingdom of God.”

**Note:** Jesus not eating the Passover could be seen as a violation IF Passover was THAT day, (Numbers 9:13).

> **NASB, Luke 22:36** - And [Jesus] said to them [after supper], “... whoever has a ***money belt*** is to take it along, ... ***also a bag***, and whoever has no ***sword*** is to ***sell*** his coat and ***buy*** one, ***[to fight the temple guards???]***. **37** ... **38** They said, “Lord, look, here are two swords.” And He said to them, “It is enough.”
>
> **NASB, Luke 22:55** - After ***they*** had ***kindled a fire*** in the middle of the courtyard ***[this is beyond belief, under Sadducean rule]*** and had sat down together, Peter was sitting among them ...

**Note:** Does "They" include Peter?  At the very least, it includes the Chief Priests, Captains of the Temple, the Elders, etc, v.52.

---

## 2. Bases for the Commands :

> **Against Teaching Others to Disobey Moses : NASB, Matthew 5:19** - Whoever then annuls one of the least of these commandments, and teaches others to do the same, shall be called least in the kingdom of heaven; but whoever keeps and teaches them, he shall be called great in the kingdom of heaven.
>
> **Against Working : NASB, Exodus 12:16, (Cf. Leviticus 23:7)** - On the first day you shall have a holy assembly, and another holy assembly on the seventh day; no work at all shall be done on them ...
>
> **Against Kindling a Fire : NASB, Exodus 35:3** - You shall not kindle a fire in any of your dwellings on the sabbath day.”
>
> **To Observe Passover : NASB, Numbers 9:13** - But the man who is clean and is not on a journey, and yet neglects to observe the Passover, that person shall then be cut off from his people.
>
> **Against Gathering Wood : NASB, Numbers 15:32-36** - ... they found a man gathering wood on the sabbath day. ... 36 So all the congregation brought him outside the camp and stoned him to death with stones, just as the Lord had commanded Moses.
>
> **Against Passover at Home : NASB, Deuteronomy 16:7** - You shall ***cook and eat it in the place [at the Temple]*** which the Lord your God chooses. In the morning you are to return to your tents.
>
> **To Submit to Judges, and Officers : NASB, Deuteronomy 19:16-17** - If a malicious witness rises up against a man to accuse him of wrongdoing, 17 then both the men who have the dispute shall stand before the Lord, before the priests and the judges who will be in office in those days.
>
> **Against Carrying : NASB, Jeremiah 17:22** - You shall ***not bring a load out of your houses*** on the sabbath day ***nor do any work***, but keep the sabbath day holy, as I commanded your forefathers.
>
> **Against Bringing and Selling Goods : NASB, Nehemiah 13:15-18** - ... and they brought them into Jerusalem on the sabbath day. So I admonished them on the day they sold food. 16 ... who ... imported fish and all kinds of merchandise, and sold them to the sons of Judah on the sabbath, even in Jerusalem. 17 ... “What is this evil thing you are doing, by profaning the sabbath day?