# What is "the great tribulation" in Revelation 7:14?

Tags: revelation

> Revelation 7:14
>  I answered, "Sir, you know." And he said, "These
>   are they who have come out of **the great tribulation**; they have washed
>   their robes and made them white in the blood of the Lamb.

If I don't connect it to other verses, it seems to me that the great tribulation in Rev 7:14 is a "global" era on earth history which has not happened yet in the past. For example, the Old Testament's people were not experiencing the great tribulation era.

But from an answer from my other question [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/30889/what-and-where-are-the-springs-of-living-water-in-revelation-79-17/30891?noredirect=1#comment59325_30891) where the answer is connecting with this verse :

> Isaiah 49:10 
>  He who has compassion on them will guide **them** and
>   lead them beside springs of water.

it seems to me the "them" from the above verse is anyone who ever live on earth. This leads me to think that [the great tribulation] in Rev 7:14 is a history on individual. For example, The Old Testament Saints (Prophets) experience their own "great tribulation".

But above is my own thinking as a Non-Christian :).

So, back to the question :
What is "the great tribulation" in Revelation 7:14 ?

Thank you.

Comment: Revelation 15 is mercifully short. cf Matthew 24:22.

Answer (score 1):

The term *great tribulation* (θλῖψις μεγάλη) appears three times in the New Testament:

> Matthew 24:21 (RSV)
>
> > *For then there will be great tribulation, such as has not been from the beginning of the world until now, no, and never will be.*
>
> Revelation 2:22
>
> > *Behold, I will throw her on a sickbed, and those who commit adultery with her I will throw into great tribulation, unless they repent of her doings*
>
> Revelation 7:14
>
> > *I said to him, “Sir, you know.” And he said to me, “These are they who have come out of the great tribulation; they have washed their robes and made them white in the blood of the Lamb."*

Matthew 24:21 is very close to something found in the Septuagint version of Daniel (12:1):

> > *And at that time Michael the great prince shall stand up, that stands over the children of thy people: **and there shall be a time of tribulation, such tribulation as has not been from the time that there was a nation on the earth until that time**: at that time thy people shall be delivered, even every one that is written in the book.*<sup>*</sup>

An explanation of the *great tribulation* of Revelation 7:14 in the context of Matthew and Daniel can be found in Lawrence Farley's, [*The Gospel of Luke: Good News for the Poor*](http://amzn.to/2EioX3A):

> [Daniel's] prophecy describes the final time of crisis and judgment in Israel as “a time of tribulation [*thlipeos* in the Greek translation], such tribulation as has not been from the time that there was a nation on the earth until that time.” Obviously the Matthean reference to “great tribulation” is based on the prophecy in Daniel.
>
> This time of great tribulation seems to last throughout the
> age, for in Matthew 24: 29 the Second Coming is said to occur “immediately after the tribulation of those days.” The parallel version of this verse in Luke 21: 24 seems to confirm this, for it describes what Matthew refers to as “great tribulation” as a time of “great distress upon the land . . . [the people] will fall by the edge of the sword and be led captive into all nations; and Jerusalem will be trampled underfoot by the Gentiles until the times of the Gentiles be fulfilled”— that is, until the end of the age. Even the original prophecy of Daniel 12 states that the “time of tribulation” will be followed by the resurrection of the dead, when “many of those who sleep in the dust will awake” (Dan. 12: 2). It would seem then that in Matthew 24 the “great tribulation” is the age-long time of suffering for Israel that began with the destruction of the Temple in AD 70. This time of distress becomes paradigmatic in the Apocalypse for the age-long suffering of the Christians at the hands of their pagan foes. Just as many concepts are transposed from a Palestinian Jewish key in the Olivet Discourse to a Gentile Christian key in the Apocalypse, so it is with the concept of Israel’s “great tribulation”: it becomes “the great tribulation” (note the definite article)— the time of unparalleled suffering, lasting throughout the age and ending only when the times of the Gentiles are fulfilled, when the kingdom of the world becomes the Kingdom of our Lord and of His Christ (Rev. 11:15)

Farley notes that this interpretation of *the great tribulation* as the suffering of the Church helps resolve the difference in groups mentioned in Revelation 7.  Verse 4 gives a number of 144,000 *servants*, whereas v. 9 talks of a *great multitude which no man could number*.  Clearly the second group is much larger than the first.  He explains here:

> In 7:1–8, John receives a vision of the Church on earth, sealed and protected by God in preparation for their entering the final time of conflict. It is the Church of the final days. In 7:9–17, however, John sees a vaster multitude. This crowd comprises, not just the Church of the final days, but the Church gathered throughout all the centuries, coming from “the great tribulation,” the age-long struggle with the world. Unlike the former crowd, this multitude is vast beyond counting, stretching into the horizons of heaven. It is the Church glorified at last, fresh from its victorious struggle, an overwhelming testimony to the power of God.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sup>Brenton translation</sup>

Answer (score 0):

revelation 7 is an answer to the question in revelation 6....the question was "who will be able to stand"(verse 17) at Christ second coming .We saw the living wicked crying and moaning in revelation 6 asking rocks to fall on them. Revelation 7 answers that question.John presents the saints who will be alive and who will be able to stand.In 7:1–8, John receives a vision of the Church on earth, sealed and protected by God in preparation for their entering the final time of conflict. It is the Church of the final days.These go through  a time of trouble ( or great tribulation) such as never was .That great tribulation is recorded in revelation chapter 16  in the seven plagues climaxing at Christ second coming.There will be people who will be alive and who will be christians who will witness the falling of God s wrath and these will COME OUT OF THAT GREAT TRIBULATION ALIFE.the elder is specific as HE says "these are they who have come out of the the sixth seal great  tribulation".THE  GREAT TRIBULATION IN REVELATION 7 IS LOCALISED IN THE SIXTH SEAL BEFORE THE SEVENTH SEAL OPENS.that Great tribulation is specific for end times AND NOT SAINTS OF ALL AGES....So john saw many people from many languages COMING OUT ALIFE (NOT TASTING DEATH) after passing through the that great tribulation

learning points...GREAT TRIBULATION is something the saints will GO THROUGH AND WILL NOT AVOID IT BY disappearing with private tickets to heaven.There is no such thing is pre-tribulation rapture.

learning point....no one knows the period of years or months of the  great tribulation in revelation 7.There is no duration given.The seven years in daniel 9 do not relate to revelation 7.The seven years in daniel span the time when Christ was baptised and midway that seven year period cHRIST WAS CRUCIFIED(cut off) AND the seven years END AT THE STONING OF Stephen,WHEN THE JEWISH NATION SEALED THEIR REJECTION OF Christ Marking the end of the 70 weeks of years period

learning point.....In 7:1–8, John receives a vision of the Church on earth, sealed and protected by God in preparation for their entering the final time of conflict presented in SYMBOLS.....the 144000(symbolic number) 12 tribes of  Israelites(symbolic tribes (IN SYMBOLS) enter the great tribulation and come OUT AS victorious and revelation 9-17 is the literal description of the same group!..please note if you think that the 144000 are literal jews please note that the Great TRIBULATION they enter is the same tribulation the great multitude come out of alife...the scorching sun and thirst recorded in revelation 7:16 is experienced literally in revelation 16 when the plagues fall.Reading  through revelation 16 the SUN will literally scorch people and thirst and hunger will be experienced when fountains of rivers are unavailable etc.Revelation 7:16 promises that these who have gone through such experiences will NEVER EXPERIENCE IT AGAIN

THE GREAT TRIBULATION IN REVELATION 7 IS THE SAME AS DANIEL 12:1...THE LAST ONE BEFORE JESUS COMES......

Comment: Please see the Tour and the Help (below, bottom right) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please could you edit and remove the capital letters. _Italics_ are for emphasis. Capitals are for proper, grammatical capitalisation (proper nouns etc). Many people regard this kind of use of capitals as "shouting".

Answer (score 0):

What is "the great tribulation" in Revelation 7:14 ?

What is the Great tribulation?
Tribulation, according to Bible Hub’s definition and the Word help studies, the Greek lexicon 2347 means persecution, affliction, distress, tribulation. From thlibo 2346; thlíbō (the root of 2347 /thlípsis, reflecting an original "b"/bēta) –
properly, rub together, constrict (compress), i.e. pressed together; (figuratively) oppressively afflict (distress), i.e. like when circumstances "rub us the wrong way" that make us feel confined (hemmed in); restricted to a "narrow" place

Tribulation means a pressure (what constricts or rubs together), used of a narrow place that "hems someone in"; tribulation, especially, internal pressure that causes someone to feel confined (restricted, "without options").
2347 /thlípsis ("compression, tribulation") carries the challenge of coping with the internal pressure of a tribulation, especially when feeling there is "no way of escape" ("hemmed in").

The adjective great means exceeding, great, large on a grandeur scale, and or something on a grandeur scale; great tribulation, has Christ said, that has not took place since there was a nation, nor ever will be. It’s global.

Thus, the Great Tribulation described by Christ is not the same level of persecution or tribulations, however, it is the worse pressure, persecutions, and affliction an Elect will experience than others. Matter of fact, the great tribulation for his elect’s sake those days are shortened.

The explanation of Jesus Christ concerning the tribulations that will come over the world, some are not on the same level or degree as the Great tribulation, but they are tribulations which the saints who are suffering are found worthy of the Lord.

The Tribulation, persecution, or afflictions, we shall suffer which does NOT describes the Great tribulation:
Mark 13:10-13; Luke 21:12-18, v 12 “Persecute you”; Matthew 24:13 “afflicted” same word thlípsis 2347 persecuted or tribulation; nor in Revelation 2:10 Church of Smyrna who suffer “tribulation” dying for their faith, Antipas Revelation 2:13; the Thessalonians who suffer “Afflictions” 2 Thessalonians 1:4-6 from their country as Paul did from his, the Jews 1 Thessalonians 2:14; even Apostle John Revelation 1:9 I John, who also am your brother, and companion in tribulation, and in the kingdom and patience of Jesus Christ, was in the isle that is called Patmos, for the word of God, and for the testimony of Jesus Christ.

However, these, above, describes not that Great tribulation spoken of by the Lord, Jeremiah 30:7, and Daniel 12:1 in Matthews chapter 24.

A couple of Scriptures that reference and or describe a Great tribulation for his people:

Jeremiah 30:7 Alas! for that day is great, so that none is like it: it is even the time of Jacob's trouble; but he shall be saved out of it.

Daniel 12:1 And at that time shall Michael stand up, the great prince which standeth for the children of thy people: and there shall be a time of trouble, such as never was since there was a nation even to that same time: and at that time thy people shall be delivered, every one that shall be found written in the book.

Matthew 24:
The Emergence of the Beast or that WICKED one and the abomination of desolation stand in the holy place

Matthew 24: 15 When ye therefore shall see the abomination of desolation, spoken of by Daniel the prophet, stand in the holy place, (whoso readeth, let him understand:)
Mark 13:14 But when ye shall see the abomination of desolation, spoken of by Daniel the prophet, standing where it ought not, (let him that readeth understand,) then let them that be in Judaea flee to the mountains:

(Here is the specific time, event and person takes place: the Beast/little horn in Daniel 8:9-12; ch 11:36 claims to be god or that is called God 2 Thessalonians 2:3-4. The time line discussed below.)
Starting from this point, verse 15, where the abomination of desolation, “Stand in the holy place” is the commence of the Great tribulation.

(Luke 21:20 the desolation or when the armies are surrounding Jerusalem; this is referring to 70 AD when Jerusalem was destroyed. It is not the same as Mathew and Marks account of the abomination of desolation or the BEAST/Antichrist)

Time is shortened for the Elect’s sake:
Matthew 24:22 And except those days should be shortened, there should no flesh be saved: but for the elect's sake those days shall be shortenedMark 13:20-21.

The Lord’s concern for the Elect and the False Christs and False prophets shewing great signs and wonders

Matthew 24:24 For there shall arise false Christs, and false prophets, and shall shew great signs and wonders; insomuch that, if it were possible, they shall deceive the very elect.
Mark 13:22 For false Christs and false prophets shall rise, and shall shew signs and wonders, to seduce, if it were possible, even the elect.

The most important point to make is the two prophets who prophesies for three and a half years, finishes their testimony, are killed by the Beast; they were in the Great tribulation time period, thus, the Great tribulation did not occur before they emerged from the scene.

Furthermore, women who is the children of israel will be #1 taken care of and protected #2 from the *face of the serpent* (the Beast or Antichrist) for 3 and a half years.
#1 Revelation 12:6 And the woman fled into the wilderness, where she hath a place prepared of God, that they should feed her there a thousand two hundred and threescore days. 14 And to the woman were given two wings of a great eagle, that she might fly into the wilderness, into her place, where she is nourished for a time, and times, and half a time, from the face of the serpent. Thereby, all Israel being saved Romans 11:26, Daniel 12:1, Jeremiah 30:7, and Revelation 12 women represents all Israel: men, women, children, and infants will be delivered/saved.

#2The two prophets are prophesying for 3 and a half years. They are visibly and CLEARLY there within the exact timeline of the Beast. Revelation 11:3 3 And I will give power unto my two witnesses, and they shall prophesy a thousand two hundred and threescore days, clothed in sackcloth. Revelation The Beast years he reigns are 3 and a half years, interesting.

The beast, the Antichrist, or Wicked one arises out of the bottomless pit and kills the two prophets.

#3 Revelation 11:7 And when they shall have finished their testimony, the beast that ascendeth out of the bottomless pit shall make war against them, and shall overcome them, and kill them.
Also, to take note, the Beast rules for 3 and a half years.
Revelation 12:14 And to the woman were given two wings of a great eagle, that she might fly into the wilderness, into her place, where she is nourished for a time, and times, and half a time, from the face of the serpent.
Revelation 13:5 And there was given unto him a mouth speaking great things and blasphemies; and power was given unto him to continue forty and two months. This is 3 and a half *years:* same timeline as the TWO prophets.

#4 This beast and false prophet are destroyed or killed by Jesus  Christ in Revelation chapter 19:20,21.
In 2 Thessalonians 2:8 And then shall that Wicked be revealed, whom the lord shall consume  with the spirit of his mouth, and shall destroy with the brightness of his coming.

**As a result, notice the *time line:* #1, the women representing the children of Israel are saved from the beast; #2 it was the beast who kills the two witnesses; thereby, #3, the two prophets are in the timeframe of the Beast; #4, it is Jesus Christ who destroys the beast or antichrist.
Therefore, it’s all in the same period. Thus, the great tribulation is in the timeline of the Women/all Israel being Saved, the two prophets, the Beast, and the Lord from Heaven who destroys the Little horn/Beast.

Matthew 24:29 “Immediately after the tribulation of those days…”   and Mark 13:24, “But in those days, after that tribulation…” AFTER, the Great tribulation, the two prophets are  heavens and earth are shaken; the power of heaven is shaken

An example, of an external and internal conflict in Christians, in nations experiencing a great tribulation, having pressure, feeling compressed or hemmed in, is in Revelation 13:16-17 shown below; it details all people: great, small, poor, rich, free or bond will have to receive a mark, upon their foreheads or in their right hands; mark in their right hands is possibly, a Radio-frequency identification (RFID) chip; externally, resulting in an economic deprivation and or being financially cutoff for those who does not receive the mark: buying groceries, nor selling any product/merchandise is not an option.

Also, the internal struggle would be for saints/Christians not give in to worship the beast neither his image as Revelation 14:9, 11-12 & Revelation 15 shown below; we need to have patience so we, as the Lord said can, “possess ye your souls” Luke 21:19.
Those who succumbs to the tribulation, affliction, or pressure and worships the beast, having the number of the beasts name or receiving said mark, are economically free to purchase or to buy and sell merchandise or product, groceries etc.

Revelation 13:16And he causeth all, both small and great, rich and poor, free and bond, to receive a mark in their right hand, or in their foreheads: 17And that no man might buy or sell, save he that had the mark, or the name of the beast, or the number of his name.

Revelation 14:9And the third angel followed them, saying with a loud voice, If any man worship the beast and his image, and receive his mark in his forehead, or in his hand…11And the smoke of their torment ascendeth up for ever and ever: and they have no rest day nor night, who worship the beast and his image, and whosoever receiveth the mark of his name. 12Here is the patience of the saints: here are they that keep the commandments of God, and the faith of Jesus.
Scriptures which refers to, and or describes a Great Tribulation:

Luke 21:19 In your patience possess ye your souls.

The term Great Tribulation was first coined by the Lord; Jesus Christ quotes Daniel 12:1 specifically, and had Jeremiah 30:7 in mind, in Matthew 24:21 For then shall be great tribulation, such as was not since the beginning of the world to this time, no, nor ever shall be. Mark 13:19 For in those days shall be affliction, such as was not from the beginning of the creation which God created unto this time, neither shall be.

Daniel 7:25 And he shall speak great words against the most High, and shall wear out the saints of the most High, and think to change times and laws: and they shall be given into his hand until a time and times and the dividing of time.

Daniel 12:1 not as the great tribulation but as “A time of trouble, such as never was since there was a nation even to that same time”; this time of trouble is referring to israel “the children of thy people” and “the saints”: Gentiles believers.

Daniel 11:36 And the king shall do according to his will; and he shall exalt himself, and magnify himself above every god, and shall speak marvellous things against the God of gods, and shall prosper till the indignation be accomplished: for that that is determined shall be done.
Daniel 11: And arms shall stand on his part, and they shall pollute the sanctuary of strength, and shall take away the daily sacrifice, and they shall place the abomination that maketh desolate…

The Great Tribulation was first introduced, as “Great” in Jeremiah, as Jacobs trouble. Then the prophet Daniel provides the timeframe of this “time of trouble” he says it’s a time, times and half of a time; The Lord thru Daniel informs us its connected to Jeremiah 30:7 by the use of similar language Daniel 12:1 “and there shall be a time of trouble, such as never was since there was a nation even to that same time: and at that time”; notice, both Jeremiah and Daniel state that Israel shall be saved from it above: this is the same event describe in Jeremiah.

I think some of Daniel prophecies  in chapter 7, 8 and 11 represent a type and shadow of Babylon, Medo Persia, Greece, Rome’s rulers; a type of little horn in Antiochus Epiphanes iv or of some figure in the past.

However, the book of Daniel prophecies are pointing to a future time and fulfillment of the little horn, the Beast or Antichrist in a future period.

Jesus Christ quotes partially Daniel 11 in Matthew 24:15 When ye therefore shall see the abomination of desolation, spoken of by Daniel the prophet, stand in the holy place, (whoso readeth, let him understand:); some suppose this could be destruction of the temple in AD 70 wherein these prophecies were fulfilled; however, looking at the time line, it is even a more distant future.
Therefore, the Great tribulation is not anyone who has ever lived on earth but referring to a particular time that takes place in the future.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Answer (score 0):

**What is "the great tribulation" in Revelation 7:14?**

Revelation 7:14 is part of the vision of the book that was sealed with seven seals (Rev 5:1). That vision begins in 4:1 and ends in 8:1. Other parts of Scripture may help but **this great tribulation must be understood first and foremost in the context of the vision of the sealed book**.

These people who “*come out of the great tribulation*” (7:14) are “*clothed in the white robes*” (7:13). They are, therefore, the same as “*the souls of those who had been slain because of the word of God*” (6:9) who were “*given to each of them a white robe*” (6:11). These are the people who were slaughtered in the great tribulation.

This description of God's slain people is the fifth seal (6:9-11) and the end result of the previous four seals:

> In the second seal: “*a red horse, went out; and to him who sat on it,
> it was granted to take peace from the earth, and **that men would slay
> one another**; and a great sword was given to him*” (6:3-4).

> The third seal symbolizes famine (6:5-6).
>
> The fourth seal: "*An ashen horse; and he who sat on it had the name
> Death; and Hades was following with him. Authority was given to them
> over a fourth of the earth, to **kill with sword and** with famine and
> with pestilence and by the wild beasts of the earth.*" (6:7-8)

To understand the great tribulation, we need what these seals are.

I will give you my interpretation:

> [Jesus received the sealed book at His ascension](https://revelationbyjesuschrist.com/revelation-5/). Consequently, He
> began to break the seals at that time.
>
> [The first seal is the gospel going out](https://revelationbyjesuschrist.com/white-horse/).
>
> Since the first seal is the gospel and the fifth shows
> God’s slain people, the killing in the intermediate seals are the
> killing of God’s people as they proclaim God’s word.

**Conclusion**: The great tribulation is not a specific period. It is a description of the experience of God’s people during the entire church age.

Answer (score -1):

The great tribulation in Rev. 7:14 corresponds with a number of passages in both the Old Testament and the New Testament.  In the Old Testament, especially in the prophets there were numerous prophecies concerning a time of trouble that would come to the people of Israel.  One of the prime examples of this is found in Jeremiah 30 where it is called the time of Jacob's trouble.  In Daniel it is his 70th week and also it is found in Zechariah.  That this time of trouble was after the captivity can be seen in both the Daniel passages and in the Zechariah passages.  Other passages include Isaiah 2, Micah 5, and Zephaniah 1.  In these various passages it goes by different names, but the point is judgment that will bring about the restoration of Israel.

That it will last seven years comes from the seventieth week of Daniel.

In the New Testament it is found in Revelation 6-19 and there is a great deal of detail concerning nature of the judgments that will come upon the whole earth.  The other place that it is found in the New Testament is the three places where the gospels record the event called the Olivet discourse.  The largest example of the Olivet Discourse is found in Matthew's account in Matthew 24-25.  There too, the tribulation is marked by two halves with the first 3 1/2 years being called the tribulation and the last 3 1/2 years being called the great tribulation.

Of course all of these interpretations are based on a Christian view of these events from a literal dispensational hermeneutic.  There are some Christians who hold to a Covenant theology hermeneutic that consider these events to have already been fulfilled, either partially or in full.  They generally go by the name preterists or partial preterists.  Finally there are some Christians who spiritualize the entire book of Revelation as well as the judgment scenes in the Old Testament.

Answer (score -1):

Great tribulation that the saints went through is the trouble they received from the world. In the words of Jesus:

John 16:33

> 33 These things I have spoken unto you, that in me ye might have
> peace. In the world ye shall have tribulation: but be of good cheer; I
> have overcome the world.

There is a difference between the tribulation the saints are currently enduring from the world and the tribulation that the world is going to be recompensed by God:

2 Thessalonians 1:4-10

> 4 So that we ourselves glory in you in the churches of God for your
> patience and faith in all your persecutions and tribulations that ye
> endure:
>
> 5 Which is a manifest token of the righteous judgment of God, that ye
> may be counted worthy of the kingdom of God, for which ye also suffer:
>
> 6 Seeing it is a righteous thing with God to recompense tribulation to
> them that trouble you;
>
> 7 And to you who are troubled rest with us, when the Lord Jesus shall
> be revealed from heaven with his mighty angels,
>
> 8 In flaming fire taking vengeance on them that know not God, and that
> obey not the gospel of our Lord Jesus Christ:
>
> 9 Who shall be punished with everlasting destruction from the presence
> of the Lord, and from the glory of his power;
>
> 10 When he shall come to be glorified in his saints, and to be admired
> in all them that believe (because our testimony among you was
> believed) in that day.
> The tribulation that God is going to recompense the world is the wrath of the lamb after the end of the period of Grace. Before that tribulation the saints will be taken off the scene for God to punish the world for their inequities.

Isaiah 26:19-21

> 19 Thy dead men shall live, together with my dead body shall they
> arise. Awake and sing, ye that dwell in dust: for thy dew is as the
> dew of herbs, and the earth shall cast out the dead.
>
> 20 Come, my people, enter thou into thy chambers, and shut thy doors
> about thee: hide thyself as it were for a little moment, until the
> indignation be overpast.
>
> 21 For, behold, the LORD cometh out of his place to punish the
> inhabitants of the earth for their iniquity: the earth also shall
> disclose her blood, and shall no more cover her slain.

This tribulation is the wrath of the lamb, the opening and manifestation of the sixth seal.

Revelation 6:12-17

> 12 And I beheld when he had opened the sixth seal, and, lo, there was
> a great earthquake; and the sun became black as sackcloth of hair, and
> the moon became as blood;
>
> 13 And the stars of heaven fell unto the earth, even as a fig tree
> casteth her untimely figs, when she is shaken of a mighty wind.
>
> 14 And the heaven departed as a scroll when it is rolled together; and
> every mountain and island were moved out of their places.
>
> 15 And the kings of the earth, and the great men, and the rich men,
> and the chief captains, and the mighty men, and every bondman, and
> every free man, hid themselves in the dens and in the rocks of the
> mountains;
>
> 16 And said to the mountains and rocks, Fall on us, and hide us from
> the face of him that sitteth on the throne, and from the wrath of the
> Lamb:
>
> 17 For the great day of his wrath is come; and who shall be able to
> stand?

The true blood washed saints will not pass through this tribulation of the wrath of the lamb.

Luke 17:26-30

> 26 And as it was in the days of Noe, so shall it be also in the days
> of the Son of man.
>
> 27 They did eat, they drank, they married wives, they were given in
> marriage, until the day that Noe entered into the ark, and the flood
> came, and destroyed them all.
>
> 28 Likewise also as it was in the days of Lot; they did eat, they
> drank, they bought, they sold, they planted, they builded;
>
> 29 But the same day that Lot went out of Sodom it rained fire and
> brimstone from heaven, and destroyed them all.
>
> 30 Even thus shall it be in the day when the Son of man is revealed.

The saints of revelation 7:14 who were before the throne are the raptured saints. At this time God deals with Israel and seals the
144000. This chapter during the sixth seals, two scenes come in preview, earth where the 144000 are being sealed, God dealing with the Jews. The second scene is heaven where blood the saints of all ages are gathered before the throne.

Answer (score -2):

My answer on Revelation will be different than anyone on this forum but I think it will satisfy your question.

In short, Rev. 7:14 refers to the great tribulation as in Babylon, the harlot, killing all believers (Rev 17:5-8). The book of Revelation may have the most allusions to the Old Testament in any book in the New Testament, however the story is the time of writing forward. The best way to understand who are the believers is to follow the white robes. The robes gives us the clues as to what is the great tribulation.

Below are the relevant passages as to who are the believers in Rev 7:14. Please note the Hebrew Poetry (how the text compare and contrast things such as living and dying, clothed and naked, seeking to be avenge and cursing).

**The Fifth Church (Rev 3:1-6):**

- The church in Sardis believe they are alive but Jesus tells them they are dead (Rev 3:1).
- Those that don't soil their white robes will walk with Jesus (Rev 3:4-5).

**The Fifth Seal (Rev 6:9-11):**

- The believers are dead (martyred) but living below the throne of God (Rev 6:9).
- The believers were given a white robe and told to wait a little longer until the numbers are complete (Rev 6:11).

**The Believers in Heaven (Rev 7:9-17; continuation of Rev 6:9-11).**

- The believers are in heaven and comforted (Rev 7:15-17).
- The believers are given white robes (Rev 7:9).

**The Fifth Trumpet (Rev 9:1-11):**

- The unbelievers are alive but wished they are dead (Rev 9:5-6).
- They will be in pain for 5 months and will seek death but not find it (Rev 9:5-6).

**The Fifth Bowl (Rev 16:10-15):**

- The unbelievers live on earth, in pain, curse the believers in heaven (Rev 16:10; see Rev 6:9-11 where the believers in heaven seek Jesus to avenge those who killed them on earth).
- Jesus will come like a thief, a warning that they should not be caught naked (Rev 16:15).

**The Saints Avenged (Rev 19:1-8):**

- Great multitude in heaven praising God for the destruction of Babylon (Rev 19:1-6).
- The saints where the robes of righteousness (Rev 19:8).

**The Second coming (Rev 19:11-21):**

- The great multitude ride with Jesus to defeat the beast (Rev 19:11-21).
- They wear white robes (Rev 19:14)

**Satan Bound for 1,000 Years (Rev 20:1-6):**

- Satan imprisoned for 1,000 years (Rev 20:1-3).
- The saints wearing white robes and judging with Jesus (Rev 20:4-6).

I encourage you to read the main passages in bold because they tell a story that is easily missed reading Revelation normally. Revelation has many more of these storylines that span the entire book.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Kim Lewis. If I'm correct to get what you mean, so the "them" in Isaiah 49:10 is not talking about "the great multitude" as it read in Revelation 7. The "great multitude" in Revelation 7 is talking about specific individuals who are experiencing "the Babylon" time, the great tribulation era. Please CMIIW, Kim Lewis.

Comment: Karma, you are correct on the Isa 49:10 reference. It was a source that John used in Rev 7:9-14. I looked it up in my book, How John Wrote the Book of Revelation: From Concept to Publication and there it was. It only shows I need to read it more often.

If you are interested in how John constructed all of Revelation using the Hebrew Scriptures I would recommend reading it. It will take you through the process of how it was written. It is rated high by Atheists and Ministers alike which is an accomplishment in itself.