# What part of man gets saved?

Tags: soteriology, soul, spirits, body

Which part of man Gets saved?

Body? Soul? Spirit?

Or the whole?

> **Matthew 24:22 (KJV)**
>   And except those days should be shortened, there should no flesh be saved: but for the elect's sake those days shall be shortened.
>
> **John 10:9 (KJV)**
>   I am the door: by me if any man enter in, he shall be saved, and shall go in and out, and find pasture
>
> **1 Corinthians 3:15 (KJV)**
>   If any man's work shall be burned, he shall suffer loss: but he himself shall be saved; yet so as by fire.
>
> **1 Corinthians 5:5 (KJV)**
>   To deliver such an one unto Satan for the destruction of the flesh, that the spirit may be saved in the day of the Lord Jesus.
>
> **1 Peter 1:9 (KJV)**
>   Receiving the end of your faith, even the salvation of your souls.

Comment: I pray God your whole spirit and soul and body be preserved blameless unto the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ. I Thessalonians 5:23 [KJV].

Comment: Please expand on it

Comment: @NigelJ According to 1 Thessalonians 5:23, blamelessness is only "***unto** the coming our Lord Jesus Christ*". Perhaps the OP wants to know about the "final state" of things. I think a fuller answer is required.

Comment: "Do not be afraid of those who kill the body but cannot kill the soul. Rather, be afraid of the One who can destroy both soul and body in hell". (Mat 10:28). "it is sown a natural body, it is raised a spiritual body. If there is a natural body, there is also a spiritual body" (1 Cor 15:44)

Comment: I am curious about the spiritual body. Jesus apparently had a spiritual body after resurrecting from the dead. Because he could seemingly walk through walls with it, as well as disappearing and emerging at will. I assume that the 144000, who will be priests of God in Jerusalem during the millennium, will live in these kind of spiritual bodies.

Answer (score 1):

In a previous [answer on this site](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13524/in-hebrews-412-what-is-the-difference-between-%cf%88%cf%85%cf%87%e1%bd%b5-soul-and-%cf%80%ce%bd%ce%b5%e1%bf%a6%ce%bc%ce%b1-spirit/30528?noredirect=1#comment86885_30528) I expressed from scripture that humanity is spirit, soul and body as the apostle says :

> I pray God your whole spirit and soul and body be preserved blameless unto the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ. I Thessalonians 5:23 [KJV].

In your question you quote from Jesus' words :

> I am the door: by me if any man enter in, he shall be saved, and shall go in and out, and find pasture. [John 10:9, KJV.]

Ergo, if any 'man' 'shall be saved' then for a humanity to be saved requires the whole humanity to be saved, namely, 'spirit and soul and body'.

To be preserved blameless, necessitates salvation, for humanity is seen in scripture to be guilty of sinful deeds, to be sinful in nature, and to be corrupt from the heart.

Salvation is to be saved from all of this. And to be 'preserved blameless' from a point of time until the coming of the Lord (whether one is alive at that time or whether one's body is in the grave) must, of necessity, involve a mighty salvation of spirit, soul and body.

Salvation includes the sufferings of Christ when he :

> ... bore our sins in his own body on the tree. [I Peter 2:24, KJV.]

and includes the eradication of sin, itself, through the death of Christ :

> He hath made him sin for us (who knew no sin) that we might be made righteousness of God, in him [I Corinthians 5:21, KJV.]

And salvation includes the resurrection of the body :

> Jesus said unto her, I am the resurrection, and the life: he that believeth in me, though he were dead, yet shall he live. [John 11:25, KJV.]

This question is quite broad in scope and includes justification, redemption, remission, propitiation, reconciliation and final resurrection.

Answer (score 0):

**What part of man gets saved?**

When a person dies he ceases to exist , nothing is saved , when Adam  was confronted by God for his disobedience, God said : **" By the sweat of your face  you shall eat bread till you return to the ground, for out of it you were taken; for you are dust  and to dust you shall return.”Genesis 3:19  (ESV)**   So when God told Adam that he was returning  to  dust , this meant that he returned to  a condition of nonexistence."

The wise King Solomon observed that the living know that they will die and that the dead know nothing, they can neither love or hate in sheol [grave] in which you are going.

Ecclesiastes 9:5-6, 10  (ESV)

> "For the living know that they will die, but the dead know nothing,
>   and they have no more reward, for the memory of them is forgotten. 6
>   Their love and their hate and their envy have already perished, and
>   forever they have no more share in all that is done under the sun.10
>   Whatever your hand finds to do, do it with your might,[a] for there is
>   no work or thought or knowledge or wisdom in Sheol, to which you are
>   going."

Jesus said:" Our friend Lazarus has fallen asleep, the disciples thought that Jesus was referring to  a literal sleep, then he explained:"Lazarus is dead." Notice that Lazarus was not in heaven (John 3:13) or  being tormented in hell, or visiting his ancestors, he was simply at rest in death.

John 11:11-14 (NASB)

> 11 "This He said, and after that He *said to them, “Our friend Lazarus
>   has fallen asleep; but I go, so that I may awaken him out of sleep.”
>   12 The disciples then said to Him, “Lord, if he has fallen asleep, he
>   will [a]recover.” 13 Now Jesus had spoken of his death, but they
>   thought that He was speaking of literal sleep. 14 So Jesus then said
>   to them plainly, “Lazarus is dead."

The hope of resurrection, **notice, all those in the grave/tombs** will hear Jesus voice and come out.

John 5:28-29 (KJV)

> 28 "Marvel not at this: for the hour is coming, in the which **all that
>   are in the graves shall hear his voice,** 29 And shall come forth; they
>   that have done good, unto the resurrection of life; and they that have
>   done evil, unto the resurrection of damnation."

Answer (score 0):

The Greek of 1 Thessalonians 5:23, I see like this:

> Furthermore, the God of peace himself, may he sanctify you completely, and your whole being (spirit, soul and body), blamelessly till the appearance of our Lord Jesus Christ may it be kept.

Details:
[image]

The word to note here is the adjective *ὁλόκληρον* (Nominative-Neuter-Singular, meaning whole/entire), from *ὁλοτελής* ([Strong's G3651](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/Lexicon/Lexicon.cfm?strongs=G3651&t=KJV) - holotelēs).

An adjective without a noun to modify, modifies a generic noun (i.e. a person/place/thing), so I have chosen "being" as the "thing" that *ὁλόκληρον* is modifying. Of course, the parts of "being" given here by Paul, follow as "spirit", "soul" and "body" (all Nominative-Singular).

This "being" Paul is praying God might sanctify completely, he also prays that God might keep it blameless until the return of the Lord Jesus Christ.

The Greeks had no need of dissecting their language in this way, but for non-native readers it's essential.

**Conclusion**
Paul is suggesting that one's "entire being" is saved: spirit, soul and body.

For those interested in Paul's thoughts on the manner in which the body is saved, please read 1 Corinthians 15:35-44.

Comment: So when we believers declare now that we are saved. Are we correct?

Comment: @FaithMendel Well only you would know what you've been saved from in this life. But for me, I only need to look at my life before I was saved, and after. When you adhere to God's principles of life, you are saved from the consequences of not doing so. Again, only you and God would know how that has played out for you.

Answer (score 0):

#### With respect to the body

> “I tell you this, brothers: **flesh and blood cannot inherit the kingdom** of God, nor does the perishable inherit the imperishable.”
> ‭‭1 Corinthians‬ ‭15:50‬ ‭

A human is a triad. The body is the housing. The housing is dynamic, it has preferences but is also corrupted by sin, making it perishable and therefore mortal. Sin exists because of the law or the knowledge of good and evil.

> “The sting of death is sin, and the power of sin is the law.”
> ‭‭1 Corinthians‬ ‭15:56‬ ‭

Paul, the sent one, writes about the body/flesh being under the power of sin

> “For we know that the law is spiritual, but I am of the flesh, sold under sin.”
> ‭‭Romans‬ ‭7:14‬ ‭

This body awaits transformation, in its current form it will not be saved.

> “And not only the creation, but we ourselves, who have the firstfruits of the Spirit, groan inwardly as we wait eagerly for adoption as sons, **the redemption of our bodies**.”
> ‭‭Romans‬ ‭8:23‬ ‭

απολυτρωσιν - The bodies must be, in English, redeemed, or receive deliverance (from sin and mortality). They essentially are replaced, changed, engulfed by the new bodies

#### With respect to the soul

> “Do not be conformed to this world, but be **transformed by the renewal** of your mind, that by testing you may discern what is the will of God, what is good and acceptable and perfect.”
> ‭‭Romans‬ ‭12:2‬ ‭

The soul which is further qualified as the will, mind and emotion, all immaterial but intricately connected to the body, is in the process of being saved. Regenerated.

#### With respect to the spirit of man

> “No one born of God makes a practice of sinning, for God’s seed abides in him; and he cannot keep on sinning, because he has been born of God.”
> ‭‭1 John‬ ‭3:9‬ ‭

The seed is the Word of God. To be born of God is to be a new spirit, John 3:6. This part of man doesn’t need saving because it cannot sin. It is of God.

> “Therefore, if anyone is in Christ, he is a new creation. The old has passed away; behold, **the new has come**.”
> ‭‭2 Corinthians‬ ‭5:17‬ ‭

#### With respect to passing through the final gate

In order to continue on in the kingdom to come, humans will need all three, a new body, a transformed soul and their new spirit.